# Error in View : invalid caption argument

Tags: r, dplyr

Estava mexendo no seguinte script:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(dplyr) 
library(readxl) 

cirurgia <- read_excel("C:/Users/Agnes/Desktop/Coisas com R/R/2_MIOMECTOMIA_HISTERECTOMIA-MAR_SET-2017.xlsx", 
                       sheet = "Plan1", 
                       col_types = c("text", "text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")) 
View(cirurgia) 
pretas <- cirurgia %>% 
 select(estado, PROCEDIMENTO, PRETA, PARDA, TOTAL) %>% 
 filter(PROCEDIMENTO == "HISTERECTOMIA TOTAL") %>% 
 View(pretas)
```

> Error in View : invalid caption argument

O que isso significa?

Comment: O erro está aqui, `select(cirurgia, etc`, não pode ter a dataframe no `select`. A não ser que `cirurgia` seja *o nome de uma coluna*.

Comment: eu editei a questão, agora o erro é esse :( .

Comment: Eu retiraria o `%>%` logo antes do View(pretas). Ou trocaria o View(pretas) simplesmente por View.

Comment: O que o @AiltonAndradedeOliveira está a dizer é que `pretas` ainda não existe, é o valor da instrução mas só depois de ter completado. Basta `View` com ou sem `()` vazios. E depois, na linha seguinte, sem o pipe `%>%`, pode ser `View(pretas)`. Ah, se carrega o pacote `tidyverse` o `dplyr` também é carregado.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(cirurgia)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(cirurgia, 20))`?

Answer (score 2):

O que está acontecendo aqui é independente da sua base dados.

> Lembre que o operador `%>%` faz com que o objeto a sua esquerda seja usado como argumento da função que está a sua direita.

Portanto, as duas linhas a seguir são equivalentes:

```
mtcars %>% View()
View(mtcars)
```

Quando você faz:

```
x <- mtcars %>% View(x)
```

Você está fazendo algo equivalente a:

```
x <- View(mtcars, x)
```

No entanto, a variável `x` ainda não existe, então isso fica equivalente a:

```
x <- View(mtcars, NULL)
```

Acontece que o segundo argumento da função `View` é um título para a tabela e esse título não pode ser `NULL`, por isso o erro:

> Error in View : invalid caption argument

Comment: Acho que entendi, muito obrigada!